# Why is defining JS prototype functions separately faster than in a dictionary?

Tags: javascript, performance, prototype

This may seem like a particularly obscure point, however I am attempting to improve my grounding in the Javascript language as a whole (more specifically its best and most efficient practices).

Whilst testing a theory in http://jsperf.com/ I came up with some odd results:

Suppose we have two "identical" prototypes, defined as follows:

**Object1**

```
var Object1 = function() {}

Object1.prototype.defaults = {
    radius: 400,
    up: 1
}

Object1.prototype.centerOffset = function() {
    return this.defaults.radius*this.defaults.up;
}
```

**Object2**

```
var Object2 = function() {}

Object2.prototype = {
    defaults: {
        radius: 400,
        up: 1
    },

    centerOffset: function() {
        return this.defaults.radius*this.defaults.up;
    }
}
```

**Object1** has a consistent (if marginal: ~3%) speed advantage over **Object2** when performing the following simple operations:

```
var o = new Object1();
var offset = o.centerOffset();
```

&

```
var o = new Object2();
var offset = o.centerOffset();
```

You can run the tests yourself [here](http://jsperf.com/correct-way-to-declare-prototype-functions). I am using Chrome 25 on OSX 10.6.8.

What I would like to know is this:

- What is the reason(s) for this performance difference?
- Is this performance indicative of some best practice in javascript?

Thanks in advance guys.

EDIT: Thanks for the responses - as some have mentioned, further testing on my part seems to suggest that this issue is browser (or rather, Javascript compiler specific). I've tested additionally in Safari, IE 10 and Firefox. IE 10 and Firefox both gave results so close as to be no different. Safari executed the operations on Object2 slightly faster than those on Object1 (around 2% on average). I would like to know what the outlier (Other) is though, as the performance difference in that case appears to be substantial.

Comment: It's probably just indicative of some quirk of V8.

Comment: I had the opposite result running firefox

Comment: Fascinating, so its compiler specific ... I'll do some more browser tests and report back.

Comment: @HugoFirth: There are always going to be different optimizations in different implementations. Don't worry about it, and don't code around them since that can change on the next release.

Comment: Why does it matter what the `(Other)` is? Are you going to write code exclusively for this unknown browser?

Comment: @thesytem I merely meant that as a point of interest. Nothing more than academic curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare a function, its prototype attribute is initialised with an object containing a default constructor.

With Object1, you are adding an attribute to the existing prototype function.
With Object2, you are replacing the existing prototype with a constructor-less of your own.

The two are not identical.

Why are the speeds different? Well, V8 could be adding a constructor function to your object2 prototype every time you create an instance.

Or more likely, the preexisting prototype function is implemented in machine code to make it faster, and when you assign your own object to Object2.prototype, the prototype function is now pure javascript and therefore slower.

The details are not that important, because different interpreters will handle this differently, what is important is to realize that Object1 and Object2 are not exactly the identical.

Comment: I like your response. I hadn't considered the possibility of an implementation's optimisation that I was overriding.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it offered clarification on what exactly I was asking. I suspect that in order to truly understand the particulars of what is going on here I would need to brush up on my C++ skills and have a look at the Chromium / V8 source.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something todo with that your appending the prototype within Object1 and overwriting it in Object2. To verify, I have made a second performance example: http://jsperf.com/correct-way-to-declare-prototype-functions/2

There I have added "Object1.prototype = {}" before the functions get assigned. Performance is now about the same between both Object1 and Object2 (at least in chrome).